# Understanding Johansens test better

Tags: time-series, cointegration

I'm trying to interpret the results of the Johansen Cointegration test. This [answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/how-to-interpret-the-eigenmatrix-from-a-johansen-cointegration-test) helped improve my understanding, but Im trying to figure why, in the case provided for that question, if the null is rejected for r<=2, then there is "over 99% confidence to say that all instruments A, B, and C are stationary by themselves" and there is no need to build a cointegrated portfolio? So, actually this tells us the same thing, in terms of the cointegrating relationship, as failing to reject r<=0, that is there is no cointegrating relationship at some confidence level?

Also, for the following two cases: 1) does rejecting r<=1 and not rejecting r<=2, and 2) rejecting r<=0 and not rejecting  r<=1, technically not tell us anything different? In that, I mean, both tell us we have at least two or one linear combination that is cointegrated, but whether its 2 or 1 makes no difference as long as its not 3 or 0?